# ASP.Net Core 5.0 Binding model to action with [Bind] attribute for nested child collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to bind a model in a post action method. i.e binding with the help of `[Bind]` attribute.
Where I post some fields for parent while a collection of child properties at the same time.
Supose I have parent as following

```
class Parent
{
int field0;
string field1;
string field2;
ICollection<Child> Children;
}

class Child
{
int field3;
string field4;
string field5;
}
```

at the time of binding I can choose fields to bind for simple binding like `[Bind("field1, field2")]` and to include children as well then `[Bind("field1,field2,children")]`

But I need to include some fields of children like `children("field4", "field5")`

Is there any possibility so that I can write like following

```
public IActionResult UTOneFlight([Bind("field1, field2, children(field4, field5)")] Parent p)
{
}
```

UPDATE

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UTOneFlight([Bind("FlightID, SrcAirportID, DestAirportID, FlightDate, Sector, RegistrationNo, FlightNo, CallSign, CrewMembers, EmbDetails, UpdateRemarks")] FlightViewModel f)
        {
            if (f != null && f.EmbDetails != null)
            {
                if (f.FlightID == 0)
                {
                    var flight = new Flight()
                    {
                        EmbDetails = new List<EmbDetail>(),
                        FlightType = "emb",
                        AirlineOperatorID = _user.OperatorID,
                        SrcAirportID = f.SrcAirportID,
                        DestAirportID = f.DestAirportID,
                        FlightDate = f.FlightDate,
                        Sector = f.Sector.ToString().ToLower()[0],
                        FlightNo = f.FlightNo.Trim().ToLower(),
                        CallSign = f.CallSign.Trim().ToLower(),
                        RegistrationNo = f.RegistrationNo.Trim().ToLower(),
                        CrewMembers = f.CrewMembers,
                        UpdateRemarks = f.UpdateRemarks?? f.UpdateRemarks,
                        EmbDataStatus = 'u',
                        CreatedBy = _user.UserID
                    };
                    foreach (var e in f.EmbDetails)
                    {
                        flight.EmbDetails.Add(
                            new EmbDetail()
                            {
                                PaxType = e.PaxType,
                                PaxClass = e.PaxClass,
                                AdultPax = e.AdultPax,
                                Infants = e.Infants,
                                Dips = e.Dips,
                                FOC = e.FOC,
                                TransferPax = e.TransferPax,
                                CreatedBy = _user.UserID
                            }
                            );
                    }
                    await _db.AddAsync(flight);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    //var flight = await _db.SingleAsync<Flight>(x => x.FlightID == f.FlightID);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            else
                return NotFound();
        }
```

and my models are

```
public class FlightViewModel
    {
        public long FlightID { get; set; }
        public int SrcAirportID { get; set; }
        public int DestAirportID { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
        public string FlightNo { get; set; }
        public string CallSign { get; set; }
        public DateTime FlightDate { get; set; }
        public int CrewMembers { get; set; }
        public char Sector { get; set; }
        public string UpdateRemarks { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EmbDetViewModel> EmbDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class EmbDetViewModel
    {
        public string PaxType { get; set; }
        public char PaxClass { get; set; }
        public int AdultPax { get; set; }
        public int Infants { get; set; }
        public int Dips { get; set; }
        public int Crew { get; set; }
        public int FOC { get; set; }
        public int TransferPax { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to write signature of the method like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UTOneFlight([Bind("FlightID, SrcAirportID, DestAirportID, FlightDate, Sector, RegistrationNo, FlightNo, CallSign, CrewMembers, EmbDetails(PaxType, PaxClass), UpdateRemarks")] FlightViewModel f)
```

Please have a look at

> EmbDetails(PaxType, PaxClass)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your goal and pls point it out.

Comment: @TinyWang,  I need to specify properties in the bind attribute as we do for simple binding like `public IActionResult Test([Bind("a,b,c,d")] Model m)`. This is very simple when you post data containing "a", "b", "c", "d" and "e".. in this method v only receive "a", "b", "c" and "d" because v bind to only these attributes. But incase of a property that is a collection and a custom type i.e class like children,  how can v specify properties
To achieve `public string getData([Bind("field1, field2, childCollection(field4, field5)")] Model p) { }`

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, and maybe we need you to provide us a sample of how you call your `UTOneFlight`, I mean the request body. As you can see in my code, I sent a json object with a list in it in my request, and my controller can automatically set the list to the  `ICollection<TestModel>` property.

Comment: I've no problem with posting data, the problem is that I want to make sure, that certain fields of that test model bound to my action method. e.g. if `TestModel` has properties like `TestProperty1`, `Testproperty2` and `TestProperty3`. I want to receive only `TestProperty1` every time when I post data so that the remaining properties are ignored by this action method. And this can be achieved by putting a `[Bind]` attribute in the signature. but don't know how to filter a child collection in `[Bind]` attribute

Comment: `These attributes affect model binding when posted form data is the source of values` this sentence comes from the document about model binding, so I used `[JsonIgnore] with using System.Text.Json.Serialization;`

Comment: Posting of data, either from ajax, or directly submitting form is not an issue.. Issue is how to filter required fields only at the time of binding

Comment: Hmmm, then I think you may use `HttpContext.Request` to realize your flexible binding..

Comment: You can basically have that by using `ViewModels`, why `ViewModel` usage is not an option for you?

Comment: @Eldar Obviously I am using `ViewModel`.. but don't want to create viewmodel for each `actioon`, My viewModel is used for some multiple actions. So I need to filter some data for my nested child in `ViewModel`

Comment: Creating a `ViewModel` for purpose is a good practice. Besides you can use inheritance to reduce typing the same properties again and again. The way you want requires a custom model binder mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which will require a lot of effort of using reflection and parsing the arguments of `BindAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

How do you send your request body? I test in my side and here's the result.

My model:

```
public class ParentTestModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestModel> testModels { get; set; }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public string prefix { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

==============================Update=============================

I test in my side with `[JsonIgnore]` and the property which added this annotation will be ignored and this is suitable when the request body is a json object like the screenshot above. And if you are sending the request in  `form-data` then you can use `[Bind]` annotation, I think you may have referred to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attributes-for-complex-type-targets).

[image]

Comment: in the signature you specified [FromBody]. I want to bind a model like i mentioned in my question.

Comment: I want to achieve this
`public string getData([Bind("field1, field2, childCollection(field4, field5)")] Model p)
{ }`